# Adding individual players scores together in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a paintball mini game and want to add players scores together to get total team scores. How would I go about adding Player X's and Player Y's hit count together to determine their final score?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need either a fake player or a dummy entity. Add all player's scores to its score to get the total. Creating the fake player, giving it a score of 0 and then adding all real player scores to it should all happen automagically with a command like this:

```
/scoreboard players operation fakePlayerName scoreName += @a[team=teamName] scoreName
```

You don't even have to create a new scoreboard for this, because fake players aren't included in `@a`.

Before the next execution you have to reset it again:

```
/scoreboard players reset fakePlayerName scoreName
```

Do the same for the other teams.

Comment: OP asked for team scores.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason when i use this command (in a repeat always active command block) my score for LightHits (my fake player) just continually goes up and up and up. Is there any way to just set LightHits score to the total of Hits instead of constantly adding?

Comment: @CCC Yes.  Put the command `scoreboard players set LightHits <objective> 0` into that repeat command block.  Then put a chain unconditional always active block after it with your current command.  This will reset the score to zero before doing the add operation.

Comment: Oh right, I overlooked the "team" part. The missing reset comes from changing my answer around multiple times before submitting it. And because I wrote it on my phone, without access to my PC to test it.

Comment: @Fabian I thought you were a command on demand service.  I want to spawn an ender dragon that is red but every 14.7 seconds changes color, is hostile towards only zombies, and uh... what other ridiculous things... oh each time it changes colors it switches teams, is a single command, and the command has to be short enough to be entered into chat.  All for free and I haven't tried anything or even done research.  Don't just say it's impossible, everything is possible.  ;p

Comment: Everything except the chat length should be possible. Muaha, now I've given you a challenge! If you want to discuss it, I should be able to talk in chat from 8:30 UTC on tomorrow.